# MySQL insert an unique ID for specific columns

Tags: mysql, unique, auto-increment, uniqueidentifier

In MySQL 5.5 & 5.7, if there is a table with 4 columns, "a,b,c,d"

```
a,b,c,d
1,1,0,0
1,1,0,1
1,2,0,1
1,3,0,1
```

Is there anyway that we can add another unique "ID" column (int or bigint) based on each unique combination of column a & b in the existing table?  For example:

```
ID,a,b,c,d
1,1,1,0,0
1,1,1,0,1
2,1,2,0,1
3,1,3,0,1
```

Also, assuming the column b is now a string:

```
ID,a,b,c,d
1,1,Joe,0,0
1,1,Joe,0,1
2,1,Peter,0,1
3,1,Jan,0,1
```

I have tried AUTO_INCREMENT & UNIQUE, which doesn't seem to work here, unless I missed something.  Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chubaka!

You can combine columns a and b using CONCAT and LPAD functions.

LPAD is important to avoid conflicts like:

```
CONCAT('1','10') = '110'
CONCAT('11','0' = '110'



SELECT CAST(CONCAT(a,LPAD(b,10,'0')) as UNSIGNED) id
     , a
     , b
     , c
     , d
  FROM table_a;
```

or simply

```
UPDATE table_a SET id = CAST(CONCAT(a,LPAD(b,10,'0'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Pastor   !!!  This is great in the above example! But is there better way to get an unique ID in INT/BIGINT, which can make JOINs on this unique ID faster, if the column "b" is a string?

Comment: I just add an example above where the "b" column is string. Could you enlighten?

Answer (score 1):

Write a query that assigns an incrementing number to each combination of `a` and `b`, then join that with the original table in an `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT a, b, @counter := counter + 1 AS id
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM yourTable ORDER BY a, b) AS x
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @counter := 0) AS var) AS t2
ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b
SET t1.id = t2.id
```